# fitting by polynomial.legendre and got the coefficients

Tags: numpy, polynomials, data-fitting

when I use them

```
np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit(x,y,25)
```

I got 26 coefficients while in the Legendre formula for n=25 I should have 13 coefficients what happened here?

and how can get the formula which this type fitting use?

Comment: Are you talking about this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit ? Please add at least the numpy tag.

Comment: yeah It is that  I used.

Comment: Could you show the resulting serie? Are there any coefficients close to zero? Could you inspect the return with parameter `full` set to true?

Comment: I used parameter full and  the resulting series:

Comment: my y data is cloze to zero same resulting serie:                                                                               (Legendre([ -8.72264004e-05,  -1.57713914e-05,   2.08097202e-04,.....])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the argument `deg` of the `fit` method is an integer, it specifies (in effect) *the number of Legendre polynomials to use*. For example, if `deg=3`, then the `fit` method finds the coefficients `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` such that

```
f(x) = c0*P0(x) + c1*P1(x) + c2*P2(x) + c3*P3(x)
```

is the least-squares fit to your data, where P0(x), P1(x), etc., are the Legendre polynomials.

In other words, the `fit` method computes the *series* of Legendre polynomials that fits your data best.  The `fit` method returns an instance of [`numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.html), which is (as explained in its docstring) a representation of a series of Legendre polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

It must be correct, if you supply the deg (degree), you will deg+1 coefficients. 
25 is the degree, don't forget the constant coefficient.

Comment: Thanks but what is the formula of this fit, I though it is the Legendre polynomial that has this general form in this link                                   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/legend.html

Comment: are you asking the algorithm behind the Legendre Curve fitting?